# Counting consecutive occurrences of a specific value in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a column named `info` defined as well:

```
|     Timestamp     |   info   |
+-------------------+----------+
|2016-01-01 17:54:30|     0    |
|2016-02-01 12:16:18|     0    |
|2016-03-01 12:17:57|     0    |
|2016-04-01 10:05:21|     0    |
|2016-05-11 18:58:25|     1    |
|2016-06-11 11:18:29|     1    |
|2016-07-01 12:05:21|     0    |
|2016-08-11 11:58:25|     0    |
|2016-09-11 15:18:29|     1    |
```

I would like to count the consecutive occurrences of 1s and insert 0 otherwise. The final column would be:

```
--------------------+----------+----------+
|     Timestamp     |   info   |    res   |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|2016-01-01 17:54:30|     0    |     0    |
|2016-02-01 12:16:18|     0    |     0    |
|2016-03-01 12:17:57|     0    |     0    |
|2016-04-01 10:05:21|     0    |     0    |
|2016-05-11 18:58:25|     1    |     1    |
|2016-06-11 11:18:29|     1    |     2    |
|2016-07-01 12:05:21|     0    |     0    |
|2016-08-11 11:58:25|     0    |     0    |
|2016-09-11 15:18:29|     1    |     1    |
```

I tried using the following function, but it didn't work.

```
df_input = df_input.withColumn(
    "res",
    F.when(
        df_input.info == F.lag(df_input.info).over(w1),
        F.sum(F.lit(1)).over(w1)
    ).otherwise(0)
)
```

Comment: what's the `w1` here? is there an ID field that has the order of the `info`

Comment: I'm not sure that it will work. You need a column to `orderBy` your values. PySpark doesn't keep the order when it processes data.

Comment: @samkart I have a timestamp column I omitted. M dataframe is ordere on that. The window is defined as w1= Window.partitionBy().orderBy('Timestamp')

Comment: @Babbara Then add this column in your example.

Comment: @MykolaZotko I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Adding a column counting cumulative pervious repeating values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325338/adding-a-column-counting-cumulative-pervious-repeating-values), credits to @blackbishop

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 'int').toDF('info')

df.withColumn("ID", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .withColumn("group",
            F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("ID"))
            - F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("info").orderBy("ID"))
    ) \
    .withColumn("Result", F.when(F.col('info') != 0, F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("ID"))).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
    .orderBy("ID")\
    .drop("ID", "group")\
    .show()

+----+------+
|info|Result|
+----+------+
|   0|     0|
|   0|     0|
|   0|     0|
|   0|     0|
|   1|     1|
|   1|     2|
|   0|     0|
|   0|     0|
|   1|     1|
+----+------+
```

Comment: In this example it is also counting the occurences of the 0s. As you can see in my "Result" column I only count the consecutive 1s.

Comment: @Babbara you can always use a `when()` to get rid of them

Comment: @samkart in which portion of the code? Where the group column is created?

Comment: @Babbara use `Result` to create your `res`. see `withColumn()` for the `group` field -- it is dropped in the end.

Comment: Modified to consider only the non-zeros occurences

Answer (score 3):

*tl;dr -- complicated approach*

We had a similar problem and wanted a row-by-row processing approach which looked at the previous row's calculated field. There were multiple calculations to keep track of and we resorted to an `rdd` approach and shipped our python functions to all workers for optimal distributed processing. Here something based on that approach.

creating a dummy data identical to your problem

```python
data_ls = [
    (1, 0,),
    (2, 0,),
    (3, 0,),
    (4, 1,),
    (5, 1,),
    (6, 0,),
    (7, 1,)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['ts', 'info'])

# +---+----+
# | ts|info|
# +---+----+
# |  1|   0|
# |  2|   0|
# |  3|   0|
# |  4|   1|
# |  5|   1|
# |  6|   0|
# |  7|   1|
# +---+----+
```

Our approach was to create a python function that keeps track of the previously calculated field in the current field. The function was used on the dataframe's `rdd` with `flatMapValues()`.

```python
def custom_cumcount(groupedRows):
    """
    keep track of the previously calculated result and use in the current calculation
    ship this for optimum resource usage
    """

    res = []
    prev_sumcol = 0

    for row in groupedRows:
        if row.info == 0:
            sum_col = 0
        else:
            sum_col = prev_sumcol + row.info
        
        prev_sumcol = sum_col

        res.append([col for col in row] + [sum_col])

    return res

# create a schema to be used for result's dataframe
data_sdf_schema_new = data_sdf.withColumn('dropme', func.lit(None).cast('int')). \
    drop('dropme'). \
    schema. \
    add('sum_col', 'integer')

# StructType(List(StructField(ts,LongType,true),StructField(info,LongType,true),StructField(sum_col,IntegerType,true)))

# run the function on the data
data_rdd = data_sdf.rdd. \
    groupBy(lambda i: 1). \
    flatMapValues(lambda k: custom_cumcount(sorted(k, key=lambda s: s.ts))). \
    values()

# create dataframe from resulting rdd
spark.createDataFrame(data_rdd, schema=data_sdf_schema_new). \
    show()

# +---+----+-------+
# | ts|info|sum_col|
# +---+----+-------+
# |  1|   0|      0|
# |  2|   0|      0|
# |  3|   0|      0|
# |  4|   1|      1|
# |  5|   1|      2|
# |  6|   0|      0|
# |  7|   1|      1|
# +---+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using conditional running sum to create groups then use that column for cumulative sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w1 = Window.orderBy("Timestamp")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy("Timestamp")

df1 = (df.withColumn("grp", F.sum(F.when(F.col("info") == 1, 0).otherwise(1)).over(w1))
       .withColumn("res", F.sum("info").over(w2))
       .drop("grp")
       )

df1.show()
# +-------------------+----+---+
# |          Timestamp|info|res|
# +-------------------+----+---+
# |2016-01-01 17:54:30|   0|  0|
# |2016-02-01 12:16:18|   0|  0|
# |2016-03-01 12:17:57|   0|  0|
# |2016-04-01 10:05:21|   0|  0|
# |2016-05-11 18:58:25|   1|  1|
# |2016-06-11 11:18:29|   1|  2|
# |2016-07-01 12:05:21|   0|  0|
# |2016-08-11 11:58:25|   0|  0|
# |2016-09-11 15:18:29|   1|  1|
# +-------------------+----+---+
```